# NetLogo tilt and roll issues in 3D model

Tags: netlogo

I am building a model, which turtles move to the nearest green patch (cube).

```
    nearest-patch
    facexyz nearest-patch
    fd distance nearest-patch
```

However, the angles of turtles' tilt and roll have changed after they arrive at each patch. How to make each turtle' tilt and roll to be 0 which turtle will parallel with XY plane, after they arrive on a patch. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you can use `move-to` to replace the combination of `fd` and `distance`. (And if you're just going to change the turtle's pitch and roll after it arrives anyway, there's probably no point in doing `face` before `move-to`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turtles have `pitch` and `roll` variables that you can set like any other variables. So, you can do `set pitch 0` and `set roll 0` to align them with the XY plane.

Comment: Hi Bryan, Thank you very much for your reply. I used tilt-up instead of pitch. That is why it could not work before. Your answer makes it work now. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Great! Glad it helped you. You should mark the answer as correct (the check mark next to the answer) so that people know that this question has been successfully answered.